# Broken git repo after executing dos2unix on .git/*

Tags: git, corruption

I executed  `find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;` from the root of a git repository without excluding the folder `.git`. This resulted in the total corruption of the git repository.

Output of `git status`

```
error: wrong index v2 file size in .git/objects/pack/pack-b5e3b0bb7e938e30e0d870639ba4bb3f7bf0e19b.idx
error: wrong index v2 file size in .git/objects/pack/pack-b5e3b0bb7e938e30e0d870639ba4bb3f7bf0e19b.idx
error: wrong index v2 file size in .git/objects/pack/pack-b5e3b0bb7e938e30e0d870639ba4bb3f7bf0e19b.idx
fatal: unable to read tree b840bcd3e20d09e0dcce7fa49283b912b767fdbf
```

and similar errors if I run `git fsck`

Is there a way to fix this mess?

I mainly need to recover the stashes

Comment: Unfortunately no. The `dos2unix` command isn't reversible since there are things that may look like they were "converted" afterwards, whereas they were like that to begin with. Basically you've corrupted binary files. If you have backups of the folders, now is a time to think about restoring from it, otherwise scratch the folder, clone the repository fresh and get back to work.

Comment: The stashes live inside the objects directory. May I ask what you were trying to accomplish by running this command?

Comment: This can't be good

Comment: Perhaps it's time to switch to [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) which is a faster `find` that ignore `.git` folder by default (and other things)

Comment: My goal was to convert the newlines of all the text files in the git repo (actually it was just a test to see how many had the wrong line ending by checking with git status how many are modified). I did not think about excluding the .git folder. I expected dos2unix to skip the binary files as it should, that is why I do not understand why it corrupted everything. Well at least I learned about a new command fd. Thanks.

Comment: Dos2unix binary file detection is not 100% foolproof. There is a small chance that a binary file contains only text symbols.

To find all files with DOS line endings you can run safely this command:

find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix -ic